# How should I add CiviCRM contact fields to Drupal node submit / comment submit forms?

Tags: drupal

We have occasional need to allow submissions of content (either Drupal nodes or comments on existing nodes).

What is the recommended way to expose CiviCRM contact fields on a node or comment submission form so that the person filling the form can add their contact/credit information, which is added to CiviCRM if it doesn't exist, or linked to a contact record and potentially updated if the contact already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try using [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) with [entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Answer (score 2):

If the above doesn't 'do it' for you. You can set Drupal Webforms to work on any node content, so that would be one option. Just go to eg admin/structure/types/manage/page and set Webform to be enabled.

Otherwise you could set a Drupal Webform to be a Block and expose that block in the situations where you need to catch this info. Just look in Webform tab > Form settings > Advanced Settings.

Comment: Ooh I like this! Please elaborate?

Comment: Which? The webform as a Block - just look in Webform tab > Form settings > Advanced Settings. If you mean webform on other Content types, go to eg admin/structure/types/manage/page and set Webform to be enabled.